# How do I determine which features are the 'principal components' stated in my code?

Tags: python, pca

I am conducting research on speech emotion recognition using 34 features but I tried to find the most important features using PCA.

I found the values of the principal components and the emotion with which they correlate. I tried using inverse_transform but the output differed from my dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import sys

def pca():
    df = pd.read_excel ('/Users/MaxEdelman/Documents/meanDf.xlsx')
    features = df.columns[1:35]
    x = df.iloc[:, 1:35].values
    y = df.loc[:, ['emotion']].values
    x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)
    pd.DataFrame(data=x, columns=features).head()
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
    principalDf = pd.DataFrame ( data=principalComponents, columns= 
    ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])
    finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, df[['emotion']]], axis=1 )
```

How do I determine from where these components result?

Comment: The principal components in PCA are linear combinations of the input features, so you should be able to invert the transformation with `inverse_transform(x)` (from [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.inverse_transform) )

Comment: I tried using inverse_transform, and the output values are different than any that are found in my dataset. I might be using it wrong, though, so would you be able to write up an example?

Comment: The best example is in the documentation. But the thing to remember is that the components are _not_ your input features, they're _transformations_ of your input features. So when you select only the two most informative components and inverse the transformation, you're losing the parts of the input data that are not explained by those two PCs

Comment: On the other side, besides @G.Anderson's points of view, whether your train dataset is large enough to represent the data distribution and your test data following the same distribution is another problem you should consider.